# Gram-Schmidt: Do the sets have some sort of order?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

I'm learning about the Gram-Schmidt process:

---

I have some subspace basis $A$ with three vectors:

$$A = \{a_1,a_2,a_3\}.$$

Based on it, we will create an orthonormal basis $B$ with three vectors, using the Gram-Schmidt process:

$$B = \{b_1,b_2,b_3\}.$$

Each vector in $B$ is calculated this way:

$$\begin{align}b_1 &= a_1,\\
b_2 &= a_2 - \operatorname{proj}_{b_1}(a_2),\\
b_3 &= a_3 - \operatorname{proj}_{b_1}(a_3) - \operatorname{proj}_{b_2}(a_3).\end{align}$$

---

Alright. At plain sight, I would summarize this method as follows.

The element **at index** $n$ of $B$ will be the element **at index** $n$ of $A$, subtracted by its projection over each of the **previous** elements of $B$.

As you can observe from the bold text, I seem to imply that **there is some order** in the terms of $A$ and $B$ (there is a first, a second, and a third, all ordered by an index number). This goes against my understanding of sets - a set doesn't have a particular order (that I'm aware of), so I find it odd how this formula seems to be operating on "previous" elements.

I mean, if we had $A = \{x,y,z\}$, technically, it should be equivalent to $A = \{z,y,x\}$. But wouldn't that affect the process? Would you clarify this, please?

Comment: The Gram-Schmidt algorithm doesn't work with _sets_ but with sequences (finite or countable) of vectors. If you arrange a set in a different sequence, you will generally get a different underlying set for the constructed orthonormal basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in fact, bases themselves are usually understood as sequences (in my experience anyway), just as Daniel Fischer describes. The order is very important.

For example, given a linear transformation $\phi$, say, the matrix of $\phi$ with respect to basis $\mathcal{B}=(v_1, v_2, \dots , v_n)$, denoted $M_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}}(\phi)$, is (usually) distinct from the matrix of $\phi$ with respect to $\mathcal{B}'=(v_2, v_1, v_3, v_4, \dots , v_n)$, denoted $M_{\mathcal{B}'}^{\mathcal{B}'}(\phi)$, etc.

So you're right, it will change the outcome of the process if you change the order of the basis elements, since it would be a different basis!